# VLAN setup on my PC

Tags: windows-xp, networking, ethernet, tags, vlan

I am bit new to VLAN. I want my two computers communicate through VLAN. I have following queries. As I am new to it my queries may be somewhat vague in some points. But i would like to hear from experts for my basic queries.

I have two PCs Computer A and Computer B in two different IP networks Network A and Network B Both my PC has windows OS installed.

1. How to send a VLAN(#Number) tagged packet from Computer A to Computer B and how to detect and untag the packet at Computer B? (Please provide the steps for windows OS)
2. For this action do I need to check if my ethernet card supports VLAN tagging/untagging? If yes how can I know if my card supports it or not?
3. Is the VLAN applied for Wireless ethernet controllers also?
4. Do I need any switch or router for this action?

Experts please given your inputs so that I can have a strong basic. If anyone can give some inputs how i can detect those VLAN in wireshirk, it will be helpful me also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you actually mean VPN rather than VLAN? As noted below, a VLAN is a virtual local area network and is done on switches and routers, not on hosts.

Answer (score 2):

1. VLANs usually live in the switching equipment that makes up a network backbone.  They are usually transparent to the computers at the edge of the network.
2. Any network card made in the last decade or so will support VLANs.
3. VLANs can be applied to wireless networks.
4. Yes, you want a managed layer-2 switch or better.

Comment: How I can detect in my PC if I received the VLAN tagged packets?

Comment: Just ping back and forth. If your switch is using vlans and they can talk to each other, things are as they should be.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. I just have few more foolish queries related to this. If I am getting any service like VOIP on a specific VLAN:4000(suppose) from a voip service provider in country UK and I want have that service here in another malaysia on the same VLAN port, is it possible? Do I need to untag the packets before my VOIp application can decode the packets? At which level the vlan is untagged? is it at my PC or my gateway or router? Can I really see the VLAN packets at my PC and untag it by any tool?

Comment: VLAN packets are encapsulated and decapsulated by switches and routers, not hosts. How are you connected to the VLAN? Over a VPN? What kind of gateway device do yo have? is it set up for your VLAN?

Comment: I have a DSL modem. My PC is connected to one of the ethernet port of it. It untags the vlanId and provides to my PC.